# Styling image along with caption, if it exists, in Wordpress

Tags: css, image, wordpress, border, caption

This is Wordpress-related question, but since desired solution is purely CSS-related, I posted it in here, not at [wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

In my current style, if image has no following caption, it is placed using HTML code like that:

```
<p>
    <a href="http://cnn.com/file.jpg">
        <img src="http://cnn.com/file-300x225.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="225" class="aligncenter size-medium wp-image-55">
    </a>
</p>
```

In my current style, it is styled like that:

```
img {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

Which draws simple border around it.

If there is a caption following image, entire HTML in this part is a little bit more complex:

```
<div id="attachment_55" class="wp-caption aligncenter" style="width: 310px">
    <a href="http://cnn.com/file.jpg">
        <img src="http://cnn.com/file-300x225.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="225" class="size-medium wp-image-55">
    </a>

    <p class="wp-caption-text">Caption</p>
</div>
```

Currently caption is not styled at all (as per my currently selected theme).

What I would like to achieve is to have entire `div` styled (image and caption), if there is any caption. If I'm not mistaken, that would require to style `img` (as currently) only, if it is not followed by `<p class="wp-caption-text">`. If it is, then img should not be styled at all and it second-in-row parent (`<div class="wp-caption">`) should be styled instead.

That's all for the algorithm. But how to code this in CSS (and whether it is possible at all) -- I don't know.

The simpliest solution would be to never style `img` and always style `<div class="wp-caption">` instead, no matter if there is caption following image or not. But the problem is, that Wordpress is adding that div only, if there is a caption. So styling only it, would result in no border at all, if there is only image.

Answer (score 1):

if you can use Jquery.

you can manipulate the markup then. if the pattern of your `img` and `img with caption` is going to be like that, you can do this.

```
$('img').each(function(){
    if($(this).parent().parent().hasClass("wp-caption")){
        $(this).parent().parent().addClass('img');
     }
});
```

am sure this code can be optimized even better, but it should give you an idea.

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manishmishra121/KZr6s/)

Comment: Looks awesome at first sight! Let me evaluate it and I'll problably accept your answer...